# Is anyone else experiencing random times where the CSS styling disappears on any SO site?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

Currently I am posting this on a page without any CSS style. Anyone else experiencing this?

I am using Firefox 3.5.2 and have tried refreshing (CTRL + F5) multiple times, even closing the browser. I do have Stylish installed and was using it to create a Hot Dog Stand theme, but it was inactive when this happened.

Screenshot:

[style-fail http://john.cognitivedelay.com/images/so-nostyle.png](http://john.cognitivedelay.com/images/so-nostyle.png)

Comment: Yes. I blame it on my crappy VPN.

Comment: How did sheep get into this conversation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're hitting the dynamic IP restriction throttle limits on sstatic.net -- too many requests for static resources in a given (n) second period.

This can be caused by some greasemonkey scripts, and I know of one serious Firefox bug that can cause it to happen. But in typical use, it shouldn't happen.

Comment: Though I see if from time to time, it only ever occurs on Firefox.

Comment: that Firefox bug is a BASTARD. It causes every single static resource on the page to force-reload, and every *instance* of every resource to load. It's really bad.

Comment: Bugzilla       #?

Comment: no idea, it's not my job to fix Firefox. But we have verified the bug, and that it's specific to Firefox. Results in a hailstorm of 100+ requests to the server.

Comment: At least it's not Opera this time.

Comment: I've seen this happen occasionally with IE7 but never with Firefox.

Comment: @Jeff ATwood THANK YOU for letting me know about this Firefox bug; I couldn't reproduce it reliably, but the same thing would happen to me; although I was having instances where JavaScript wouldn't load.

Answer (score 2):

When it happens next, check the status of Firebug and check to see if the download of the CSS file failed somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Our proxy eats css files sometimes.  Or, more technically, something dies in the request chain.  Refresh nearly always fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

I have before, but it was fixed with a refresh. Not sure what caused it though.