# Why are the scripts and CSS not loading on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, design

It looks like css doesn't work:

[image]

or it's only on my computer?

**UPDATE:** Screenshot above was from Chrome. When I tried to open in IE9, I get the following:

[image]
and in FireFox looks like in Chrome.

When I tried to open css directly I got the following error:

[image]

So, I think it's reason why it's not working.

Comment: Try pressing CTRL+F5 a lot

Comment: No repro here. All works fine.

Comment: do other sites seem to be missing the css as well?

Comment: Your local DNS server is probably causing the issue. Use a proxy server and test.

Comment: sometimes it's working fine, then again this ugly design. I found similar questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29431/radomly-missing-css?rq=1 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20068/is-anyone-else-experiencing-random-times-where-the-css-styling-disappears-on-any

Comment: yes, other sites too. It happened first on Friday, then now again. I'm using it at my job. On weekend from the home I didn't see any issues.

Comment: when I press CTRL+F5, one time it's okay, then press again, back without css.

Comment: not sure I can use proxy at mt job

Comment: That damned stack overlow.  Always have problems with that site, especially with the spel checker.

Comment: It seems that SO team should ask on SO how to update CSS and JavaScript :)

Comment: There's a new/different static CDN provider URL that I had to allow recently (in the last week or so)...look at what you're blocking/allowing.

Comment: that's why it stopped to work last week. btw, only meta is working without problem.

Comment: Having the same exact issue here.

Comment: it looks like that today stackoverflow is okay for me. but I still can't access css and js directly. something changed in design? btw, other stackexchange sites: some are okay, some have the same problem as stackoverflow had before.

Comment: again: sometimes is working, sometimes not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try opening:

- http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css

  and
- http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js

Directly.

If you see errors on either, investigate those.

Comment: it's blocked, I added screenshot to the question. So, I think it's reason why I have problem with css.

Comment: Ok. You need to talk to your network administrator about unblocking our CDN then.

Comment: I talked. He said Costa Rica is blocked for everybody.

Comment: We're not in Costa Rica.

Comment: They have some algorithm for detecting country (maybe using ip, I'm not sure exactly) and I don't think it works right.

Comment: According to RIPE Database it's hosted in Europe and according to [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OSR66.png) deep inside Switzerland... shouldn't it be in the U.S?

Comment: The website is hosted in NY. CDN nodes are all over the world.

Comment: okay, now I have access to these files, but some pictures and functionality still missing. I think some other css or jquery not loading.

Comment: There are a bunch of files on that host, @Alex - you'll want `cdn.sstatic.net` whitelisted entirely, not just individual files.

Comment: I can open cdn.sstatic.net directly without problem and could before. The problem only with specific files. okay, maybe I should speak with admin again.

Comment: Identify the specific files, and see what errors are occurring for them (in-browser dev tools are helpful for this). If it's something different, post the errors (otherwise, yeah, see your admin).