# How to change the layout of the Stack Overflow account

Tags: support, design, top-bar

A few days ago my account had its layout change into this format, which I find a little weird.

> [image]

I would like to change the header back to the original style like this:

> [image]

How can I do that?

Comment: It looks like some resources are failing to load. If you look in your browser's developer tools, do you see any errors?

Comment: But other stackexchange web sites are loading without a problem

Comment: Try using ctrl+f5 in your browser to see if there was a css or scripting update that was not automatically downloaded.

Comment: @Optimuskck to change it back, you need to check for errors and see what is happening.  It isn't a server-side issue, it is client-side.

Comment: @TravisJ thanks my friend . it fixed after using the keys you told me :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are the scripts and CSS not loading on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182826/why-are-the-scripts-and-css-not-loading-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using ctrl+f5 in your browser to see if there was a css or scripting update that was not automatically downloaded.

Sometimes these are cached and can cause the type of display issues you experienced. Using ctrl+f5 forces the cached content to refresh.