# CSS is unavailable

Tags: bug, cdn

Starting Friday (17-08-2012) we have problem with css on your page. 
As I check your css is stored here http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=ffb907d7e663 (cut from your main page), and this addres is unavailable.
I'm in Poland.

Could you check this?

Comment: Your ISP or work place is blocking the domain.

Comment: I try to access in from my remote server in France. Result unknown host http://cdn.sstatic.net

Comment: this looks like http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99085/unable-to-fetch-content-from-cdn-sstatic-net is come back

Comment: Could you give me IP address of http://cdn.sstatic.net/?

Comment: `sstatic.stackexchange.netdna-cdn.com [108.161.188.213]` -> over here. seems localized to your ISP/area?

Comment: I have just tested it from the following locations: Finland, VPS in Germany, VPS in France, Sweden, VPS in Netherlands. All positive. Edit: Now I'm just messing around with Tor, seems okay from many locations.

Comment: Wait.. why do you browse Stack Overflow from within remote server in the first place?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, OP is _testing_ using the remote server **after** he noticed it isn't working from his original location. Edit: I can also confirm that http://cdn.sstatic.net isn't resolving in France (at least the server I tested from).

Comment: I add 69.174.57.102 cdn.sstatic.net to my host file and this solve my problem for now.