# all CSS rules missing

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The CSS rules are missing from every page on StackOverflow. I've tried a few other sites and they are working fine, so I haven't (accidentally) disabled CSS with the web developer toolbar (for example).

[image]

I'm seeing this problem in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Yeah, same here. Temporary glitch most likely.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is anyone else experiencing random times where the CSS styling disappears on any SO site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20068/is-anyone-else-experiencing-random-times-where-the-css-styling-disappears-on-any)

Comment: Just happened for me, but it seems to have fixed itself.

Comment: Not any more. Works now for me

Comment: Confirm that problem seems to have been rectified

Comment: I actually have CSS here on Meta, but all other sites were without any CSS few minutes ago. Right now everything except Meta isn't even loading ..

Comment: That was the test run for the new "minimalist" look.

Comment: Blame [the devs](http://jsfiddle.net/yijiang/AYPpF/24/embedded/result/)

Comment: This is network wide with the exceptions of metas and A51

Comment: @Luke I lost CSS for meta only actually.

Comment: Just like the 60s fashion came back, so has early 90s web stylings. Give them a couple days to get the table-based layouts ready

Comment: And as tweeted just now: https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/298573639735980032

Comment: @BenBrocka Have you looked at the source?  It's [riddled with tables](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3110/when-and-why-did-so-start-using-tables-for-layout) already =P

Comment: It's broken again.

Comment: A hard reload (CTRL + F5 in Firefox) fixed the problem in my case.

Answer (score 5):

We experienced a major CDN failure and switched back to our local http://sstatic.net for static resources.  It has been restored.

http://status.netdna.com/2013/02/04/dns-records/

Comment: I'm still having this problem. Asked question yesterday on stack exchange referencing this post and my question was migrated here though I don't see it and this conversation appears to be closed. Now what?

Comment: Keep me posted - so far it hasn't happened to me.

Comment: Meant to respond a couple of weeks ago.... Turns out caused some kind of problem with the servers(?) in our building. I couldn't get a straight answer but the bottom line is that it wasn't my computer and it was resolved through my building's IT dept.