# What is happening to StackOverflow? CSS styles aren't loading?

Tags: bug, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [all CSS rules missing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166251/all-css-rules-missing)

What is happening to StackOverflow? I just visited today and it appears that I the CSS styles aren't loading... I tried from Firefox, Chrome, and IE and all get the same results. I rebooted each browser, cleared all cookies, and even ensured that I DO use site's CSS.

What could be wrong?

[image: SO]

Comment: It's the new `"craigslist"` skin (web 4.1 compatible). Do you have suggestions for improvement?

Comment: First of all, I'd bring back the CSS until the beta layout is created =S

Comment: @JoshMein That's not why mine is broken, i just tried to hit it for the first time in hours and am not loading any CSS

Comment: @abc123 That is just one of the many examples that can be found on meta. I have seen this question several times throughout the last week or so, and they usually result in cookies/history/something else on the users end.

Comment: It just fixed itself...

Comment: It has not fixed itself for me.