# A question is marked as a duplicate without the duplicate link

Tags: bug, status-completed, closed-questions

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166251/all-css-rules-missing) is marked as a duplicate without a corresponding link to the relevant question.

> ### marked as duplicate by Josh Caswell, Asad, animuson, Austin Henley, Manishearth Feb 5 at 2:36
>
> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question.

Looking at the [revision history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/166251/revisions) reveals that it was closed as too localized instead.

> **Post Closed** as "too localized" by Josh Caswell, Asad, animuson, Austin Henley, Manishearth

Why is it so?

Comment: Oh, the irony..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code that displays the close reason on the main question/show page made some bad assumptions about old data<sup>*</sup>.

I've changed it so that it should always match what's on the revisions page, fixing this bug.

Thanks for finding it!

<sub>* Old meaning more than two weeks old here on Meta, or when we started testing new flag/close code.</sub>